# Can remmina work with authenticator apps?

Tags: 18.04, remmina, two-factor-authentication

Set up my Ubuntu 18.04 droplet to use google-authenticator for ssh logins. It works well, but I can't see how to configure remmina to work with the authenticator. It prompts for a password instead and that fails.

I can just ssh but even connectbot on my phone can work with the authenticator so I must be missing something.

How to configure remmina to connect over ssh with authenticator apps?